# The number of non-trivial polynomial solutions of the differential equation $x^3y'(x)=y(x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I came across the following problem that says:

> The number of non-trivial polynomial solutions of the differential equation  $x^3y'(x)=y(x^2)$ is which of the following?
>   $(1)0\space (2)1 \space (3)3 (4)\infty.$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Does the $y(x^2)$ on the right side mean $y \cdot x^2$, or on the other hand that the function $y$ is evaluated at input $x^2$?

Comment: It is the function $y$ which  is evaluated at input $x^2.$

Comment: The only polynomial that could fit such a description is quadratic. So try $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and see the resulting system of equations by setting the coefficients of both sides equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a polynomial of order $n$, this reads:
$$3+(n-1)=2n \to n=2$$
Write this out:
$$2ax^4+bx^3=ax^4+bx^2+c \to ax^4+bx^2(x-1)-c=0$$
So, the answer is zero, since no such non-trivial polynomials exist (non-trivial forth degree polynomials have at most 4 real roots).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you proceed using the ansatz (thanks @user33640 for the "correction")
$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n
$$
and substitute it directly in the equation, you end up with
$$
x^3 \sum_{n=1}^N n a_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^{2n}.
$$
This means that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N n a_n x^{n+2} - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^{2n} = 0
$$
which tells you that all $a_n = 0$ for $n=2m+1$. This in turn help us to propose an improved ansatz
$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N b_{2n} x^{2n}.
$$
Again, substituting in the ode, we have
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^N 2n b_{2n} x^{2n+2} = \sum_{n=0}^N b_{2n} x^{4n}
$$
Now, the only way to this equation to be satisfied, is if 
$$
2N + 2 = 4N \quad \Longrightarrow \quad N=1
$$
Then $y(x) = b_0 + b_2 x^2$ implies that
$$
2 b_2 x^4 = b_0 + b_2 x^4
$$
which means $b_0 = b_2 = 0$ hence no non-trivial solution exist.

Comment: what is "anzat?"

Comment: @user33640:  it should be [ansatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) a trial solution which is to be verified.

Comment: @user33640 According to Wookipedia, "anzats" were a dangerous and mysterious Force-sensitive near-Human species with two tentacle-like proboscises that curled out and extended from their cheeks, with which the Anzati were able to feed upon the brains of their prey. An **ansatz** is a proposed form for the solution of an equation :)